# can not put line break for vertical space between two divs with images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<img src         style="width:200px;height:150px">
</div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<img src     style="width:200px;height:150px">
</div>
</div>
```

///////////////////
How come line break 
 not work. I want to have vertical space between divs.

Comment: I don't know why you're taking the risk of not putting all those attribute values in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your div's with `<div class="row">` add the `<br>` inside the empty row div. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7gqo4o1h/6/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class=col-sm-12>
    <div class=col-sm-2>
      <img src style=width:200px;height:150px>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class=col-sm-12>
    <div class=col-sm-2>
      <img src style=width:200px;height:150px>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply